# Ajax and PHP requesting a page and showing dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have an Ajax file I am trying to get to communicate with a PHP file, which will provide the Google home page, into a DIV I have in some HTML of the same page.

I have checked the code and the PHP file thoroughly and get no errors, yet I can't understand why nothings happening. Can someone please help me?. Thanks in advance.

Here's my ajax

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ajax page</title>
  </head>
    <body> 

<h1>AJAX page</h1>
  <div id="info">
    This content will be changed by default....
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

params = "url=google.com";
request = new ajaxRequest();
request.open("POST", "ajaxLab.php", true);

request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

request.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(this.readystate==4){
    if(this.status==200){
      if(this.responseText != null) document.getElementById("info").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      else alert("Ajax error: No data received ");
    }
    else alert("Ajax error: " + this.statusText);
  }
}
request.send(params);

function ajaxRequest()
{
  try
  {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch(e1)
  {
    try
    {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e2)
    {
      try
      {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      catch(e3)
      {
      request=false;
      }
    }
  }
return request; 
} 

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my simple php file..

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['url'])){
echo file_get_contents("http://".sanitiseVar($_POST['url']));
}

function sanitiseVar($var){
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = stripslashes($var);
    return strip_tags($var);
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "nothing happens"? Is the PHP page working? Have you tried accessing it directly? Do you have errors on? etc...

Comment: Can you use jQuery? The amount of code will be much much simpler!

Comment: I access the HTML page, expecting the Google homepage to appear in my DIV info. The PHP is just communicating with the AJAX asyncronously and after the server receives the page, then it's sent to my browser was my understanding. I'm brand new to Ajax.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery - for now this is a raw JavaScript lab, using Ajax to prepare me to learn YUI next (supposedly to simplify XMLHttpRequest() use). Thanks guys :-)

Comment: @MikeThornley Using jQuery has a lot of advantages. I have done the same thing, with passing parameters `url` with the value `google.com` right? Check it out. It should work. :)

Comment: PHP page won't work as it's using a URL posted to it from the $_POST array from the Ajax script during the HTTP POST.

Comment: If the one proposed works, then there is nothing wrong with your HTML Code / PHP Code. Now try playing around with AJAX in pure JavaScript, not using jQuery. Give a try for me in this jQuery code.

Comment: The `.load()` function I have used with the parameters to pass is a `POST` method.

Comment: This is raw JavaScript and a simpler example which I understand. As I said I'm not familiar with jQuery.

Comment: The first thing I would do is try to figure out if the problem is in the PHP or the JavaScript. Maybe try replacing `this.responseText` with `'$'+this.responseText+'$'` to see if that line is running. Also check if the PHP is receiving what you think it's receiving by just echoing out the `$_POST['url']` variable in your PHP script.

Comment: So you prefer to write 45 lines of code instead of 15 lines, just because it is easier to understand. jQuery is not that difficult to learn. Learning it from now will save you a lot of time and headaches in the long run.

Comment: @ColorWP.com some people like to understand what their 'magic' is doing.

Comment: Yeah Gareth thanks. I only use this. as the book says, that object can be reused if you want but I had thought that. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, readyState property wasn't bumpycapped. Worked after I corrected that!.

Answer (score 0):

Change the whole file this way:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ajax page</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#info").load("ajaxLab.php", {'url': 'google.com'});
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>AJAX page</h1>
        <div id="info">
            This content will be changed by default....
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Gareth there is no way to do AJAX in "pure" javascript (i.e. without some library)

Comment: Yes, cross domain Ajax is a security issue - It's using PHP module to get the file asyncronously.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'll remove my -1 when either the OP adds [jquery] to the question, or you answer the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("ajaxLab.php",
           {
                url:"google.com",
                // another_param : "its value"
           },
           function(result){ // Callback function, on success
             if(result != null)
                 $('#info').html(result);
             else
                alert("Ajax error: No data received ");
          }
    );    
});
```

Remember to include the jQuery library in the header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```